# Is this set corresponding to a bounded linear operator necessarily open?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\Lambda : X \to X$ be a bounded linear operator on a Banach space $X$. My question is whether the set
$$
\{\lambda \in \mathbb C: \lambda I - \Lambda \quad\text{is surjective} \}
$$
is necessarily open. The above set is similar to the [resolvent set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_set) of $\Lambda$, which is defined to be the set of all $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $\lambda I - \Lambda$ is invertible; I know that the resolvent set is always open. However, what about the set above?

For reference, it was a problem on a past qualifying exam (see [problem 6](http://papyrus.math.ucla.edu/gradquals/data/analysis-07W.pdf)) to prove that the set is in fact open. I'm not sure if they meant to indicate the resolvent set, or if the problem is correct as stated.

Comment: [A related thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/17087/5363) proving the stronger result that the space of surjective operators is open.

Comment: @t.b. Thanks for pointing that out, the argument is very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ such that $T := \lambda - \Lambda$ is surjective. Then $\bar T: X/\ker T \to X/\ker T$, $\bar T(x + \ker T) = Tx + \ker T$ is invertible, hence there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\bar T + \mu$ is invertible for $|\mu| < \varepsilon$.

Let $0 < |\mu| < \varepsilon$ and $y \in X$. Then there is some $x \in X$ such that $(\bar T + \mu)(x + \ker T) = y + \ker T$, which means that $Tx + \mu x + \ker T = y + \ker T$. So there is some $z \in X$ with $Tz = 0$ and $Tx + \mu x + z = y$. Then 
\begin{align*}
   (T + \mu)\left(x + \frac 1\mu z\right)
       &= Tx + \mu x + z\\
       &= y.
\end{align*}
As $y$ was arbitrary, $T + \mu$ is surjective and the set in question is open.

AB,

Comment: Thanks martini, this is very helpful.